# Cannot consume on HTML (Angular)

Tags: angular11

Im using Angular11 and Im trying to display the objects on HTML but it does not show. What am I missing? Sorry, newbie here in Angular.

data from API (it can be 1 or more result set)

```
[{"dept_id":"12345","dept_name":"FINANCE","name":"JOHN DOE"}]
```

ts file

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private service:SharedService,
     private route : ActivatedRoute) { }
  
  dept_id: any;
  detailsInfo: any=[];
  
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params : ParamMap)=> {  
      this.dept_id=params.get('id');
    });

    this.service.getDetails(this.dept_id).subscribe(data=>{
      this.detailsInfo= data;
    });

  }
```

Service file

```
export class SharedService {
readonly APIUrl = "http://localhost:63622/api";

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getDetails(deptId: any):Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl+'/Details?DeptId=' + deptId);
  }

}
```

html file

```
<div *ngFor="let items of detailsInfo; let i = index">
   <p>{{ detailsInfo[i].dept_name}}: {{ detailsInfo[i].Name}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your HTML, it should be like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of detailsInfo">
   <p>{{ item.dept_name}}: {{ item.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Another thing that may result in error is that you doesn't wait for the route subscription to complete before you make the call. On your `ts` file it should be like this:

```
this.route.paramMap
    .pipe(
        switchMap((params : ParamMap)=> {  
            this.dept_id=params.get('id');
            return this.service.getDetails(this.dept_id);
        })
    ).subscribe(data=> {
      this.detailsInfo = data;
    });
```

PS: I would recommend you to use actual types and avoid `any`, especially when you know the type that is returned;

PS2: You should unsubscribe the subscription `onDestroy` to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

As advised by StPaulis I add model. But still No data on HTML. And when I log it on console it said detailsInfo is undefined.

PS: How to destroy the subscription based on my current coding?

```
export class DeptDetails {
   Dept_Id: string;
   Dept_Name: string;
   Name: string;
}
```

data from API (it can be 1 or more result set)

```
[{"dept_id":"12345","dept_name":"FINANCE","name":"JOHN DOE"}]
```

ts file (edited based on above recommendation)

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private service:SharedService,
     private route : ActivatedRoute) { }
  
  dept_id: any;
  detailsInfo!: DeptDetails[];
  
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.paramMap
    .pipe(
        switchMap((params : ParamMap)=> {  
            this.dept_id=params.get('id');
            return this.service.getDetails(this.dept_id);
        })
    ).subscribe((data:DeptDetails[])=> {
      this.detailsInfo= data;
    });

  }
```

Service file

```
export class SharedService {
readonly APIUrl = "http://localhost:63622/api";

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getDetails(deptId: any):Observable<DeptDetails[]>{
    return this.http.get<DeptDetails[]>(this.APIUrl+'/Details?DeptId=' + deptId);
  }
}
```

html file

```
<div *ngFor="let items of detailsInfo; let i = index">
   <p>{{ detailsInfo[i].dept_name}}: {{ detailsInfo[i].Name}}</p>
</div>
```